# How build nested associative array based of a one-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have one-dimensional array, e.g.

```
$arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
```

I want convert it as follow(`var_dump` output):

```
array (size=1)
  'foo' => 
    array (size=1)
      'bar' => 
        array (size=1)
          'baz' => string '' (length=0)
```

I can use only loop(`for` and/or `foreach`). Recursive functions is not allowed. PHP as primary programming language.

Please, help me write code for this transformation.

Comment: this sounds like homework to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$r = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$res = array();
foreach (array_reverse($r) as $i) {
    $tmp = $res;
    $res = array();
    $res[$i] = $tmp;
}
echo '<pre>', print_r($res);
```